# How to apply css to jqgrid header column

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I am drawing a table with jqgrid.

I want to change the background color and text color of the header.

I am trying to change the css by applying a class to the header, how can I apply it?

I want it to apply only to specific header cells, not columns or rows.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used. As from certain version we have configurable parameter in colModel

Comment: jqgrid version is jqGrid.4.4.5 and jquery-1.12.4

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/aNAThTm5aRtQzYiO?preview

You can use #list_{column name} in css to set the header background color or text color,

```
<style>
    #list_id{
        background-color:green;
        color:white;
    }
    #list_invdate{
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
    }
</style>
```

Output:

[image]